# Assigning text from a TextField to NSString in another Class

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nstextfield, nsobject

So I have a NSObject called Player

```
Player.h
@interface Player : NSObject{
    NSString *PlayerName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, strong) NSString *PlayerName;
Player.m
@synthesize PlayerName;
```

And then in my MainViewController.h

```
#import "Player.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
Player *MainPlayer;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    Choice = TextField.text;
    [MainPlayer setName:Choice];
    NSLog(@"Choice: %@ Name: %@",Choice, MainPlayer.PlayerName);
}
```

This should work except the NSLog returns 
Choice:(input given) Name: (null)

I've tried to change my code, but nothing works :P 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I see that in *ViewController.m* you call `[MainPlayer setName: Choice]`, but the property is called `PlayerName` in the actual player class. Is that a typo? If not, this could be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it think you are missing this line.

```
MainPlayer = [[Player alloc]init]
```

Before set value of instance you need allocate object. you can allocate it in viewDidLoad.
And then set value of instance

```
 MainPlayer.PlayerName = field.text;
```

OR

```
 [MainPlayer setPlayerName:field.text];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten the first line :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for NSString properties I would use copy, not strong. This avoids thinking the NSString is immutable, but being handed an NSMutableString which then changes.

By default @synthesize will create an _propertyName variable for it, so you may find that what is happening is that your NSString *PlayerName; is simply being ignored in favour of the auto synthesized NSString *_PlayerName; member variable instead.

I would do this

dump `NSString *PlayerName;`
Remove the `@synthesize PlayerName`
Use `@property (nonatomic, retain, copy) NSString *PlayerName;`

See how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Several leads :

- Is `MainPlayer` properly initialized in `ViewController.h` ( ie not nil when you use it) ?
- the following line :

  ```
   [MainPlayer setName:Choice];
  ```

  Should instead read :

  ```
   [MainPlayer setPlayerName:Choice];
  ```

Sidenote : variable names should not start with a capital letter.

Comment: well I actually, setName is a method xD. 
And I had forgotten to initialize MainPlayer. 
Thank you for the advice and help :)